# Pointing a godaddy domain to a rackspace windows 2008 server

Tags: dns, godaddy, rackspace

Note: *Question was moved here from stack overflow after being closed as not being related to programming*

I've searched through a number of similar questions on stack overflow but to my surprise I haven't been able to find an answer to this seemingly common/trivial question.

I've set up lots of websites in the past, but never on my own windows server. I have installed wordpress and I can access my website through my server's IP address over the internet.

I've typed in the rackspace name servers into godaddy last Saturday:

[image]

The name servers were obtained from the dns records on my rackspace for this domain.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how this all works behind the scenes so I may be configuring something wrong or missing something. I've configured the domain into my cloud server's domain management as seen here:

[image: DNS management]

And I haven't done any other configuration (such as on my iis server). The problem is that I cannot visit my hosted site using the URL - only by the server IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I don't know what the problem was, but my workaround was to switch godaddy back to its own default DNS, and then I set an a-record directly to my site's ip address. Not sure how it all works, but glad it does.